# Prolog grandfather(i,i)

Tags: prolog

A (very) strange story:
I married a widow(W) who has a daughter(D). My father(F) married my stepdaughter (D). My wife gave birth to a son(s1). The wife of my father (the stepdaughter) also had a son (s2).

The goal of this project is to input:

```
grandfather(i,i).
```

and return `yes` in prolog.

Here is what I have so far:

```
%facts

father(f,i).

husband(i,w).

husband(f,d).

mother(w,d).

mother(w,s1).

father(i,s1).

mother(d,s2).

father(f,s2).

%rules

father(X,Y) :- f_in_law(X,Y).

father(X,Y) :- husband(X,Z),mother(Z,Y).

f_in_law(X,Y) :- husband(Z,Y),father(X,Z).

b_in_law(X,Y) :- husband(Z,Y),brother(X,Z).

%brother(X,Y) :- b_in_law(X,Y).

uncle(X,Y) :- father(Z,Y),brother(X,Z).

grandfather(X,Y) :- father(Z,Y),father(X,Z).
```

I traced through it to see what went wrong. `father(f,i)` is true so that's good! But `father(i,f)` is thought of as false. Any suggestions/ideas on how to correct this? I appreciate any input as I am rather new to prolog.

Comment: I start off with inputting grandfather(i,i). That means I need to check if father(Z,i) and father(i,Z) are true. Now father(Z,i) is true because of the fact father(f,i). For some reason though, father(i,f) is showing up false.

Comment: We recently had that one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429887

Answer (score 1):

Should the predicate be

```
f_in_law(X,Y) :- husband(Y,Z),father(X,Z).
```

instead of

```
f_in_law(X,Y) :- husband(Z,Y),father(X,Z).
```

Comment: I don't think there is a difference. However, I rewrote the predicate and still get a false with grandfather(i,i).

Comment: I don't speak english, then please tell me: isn't my father in law the person that married my mother *and* isn't my father?

Comment: Hmm OK. Will need to brush off the cobwebs :)

Comment: @CapelliC: There is a reason why I was going for a father in law still being a father. I know what causes me to be my own grandfather is that my father(F) is married to the daughter of my wife (D) which makes me a father of my father.

Comment: f_in_law(i,f) returns false

Comment: OK. could you remove all other predicates than the one in my answer (but retain all the facts) and try f_in_law(i,f) again?

Comment: @CapelliC: "the person that married my mother and isn't my father" is your stepfather.

Answer (score 0):

I have reformulated the riddle

```
father(i, s1).
father(f, i).
father(f, s2).

fatlaw(X, Y) :- husband(X, Z), mother(Z, Y).

mother(w, d).
mother(w, s1).
mother(d, s2).

motlaw(X, Y) :- husband(Z, X), father(Z, Y).

husband(i, w).
husband(f, d).

grandfather(X, Y) :-
    ( father(X, Z) ; fatlaw(X, Z) )
    , ( father(Z, Y) ; fatlaw(Z, Y) ; mother(Z, Y) ; motlaw(Z, Y) )
    .
```

the point seems to be that grandfather must accept fake biological offsprings (I hope this is reasonable English).

with that

```
?- grandfather(X,X).
X = i ;
false.
```